# Is there a way to see topics views when in mobile version?

Tags: feature-request

Is there a way to see topics views when in mobile version and if there isnt, is there a way to browse the websites desktop version in mobile?

Comment: Just tap "full site" link in the footer and you'll see the desktop version.